# Add a link to switch to the next tab

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Pretty simple question please : How can I add a button at the bottom called "Next" to switch to the next tab without having to get to the top of the page and click on the next tab ?

In fact, I'm copying the tab's code existing in the top of my page but it's not working.

```
    <a id="aba_2" href="#aba_2">Next</a>
```

This is the existing HTML code that you can also find here https://codepen.io/DiogoAlvaro/pen/wWzNEm :

```
    <ul id="abas" class="teste">
      <li class="selecionada"><a id="aba_1" href="#aba_1">Aba 1</a></li>
      <li><a id="aba_2" href="#aba_2">Aba 2</a></li>
      <li><a id="aba_3" href="#aba_3">Aba 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="conteudos">
      <div id="conteudo_1" class="conteudo visivel">
        <p>Conteúdo da Aba 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="conteudo_2" class="conteudo">
        <p>Conteúdo da Aba 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript code is :

```
    var abas = document.getElementById("abas");
    var conteudos = document.getElementById("conteudos");

    function limparSelecao(){
      abas.getElementsByClassName("selecionada")[0].classList.remove("selecionada");
      conteudos.getElementsByClassName("visivel")[0].classList.remove("visivel");
    }

    abas.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      var abaClicada = event.target.id;
      var itemSelecionado = abaClicada.substring(abaClicada.lastIndexOf("_"));

      limparSelecao();

      event.target.parentElement.classList.add("selecionada");
      conteudos.querySelector("#conteudo"+ itemSelecionado).classList.add("visivel");
    });
```

The problem I'm noticing is the switching functionality between tabs is working only one time. It means if I copy the same tabs' code another time it will not work.

Can you help me with this issue please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your `javascript`, when you click on a tab things will be done in the background in order to show you its content.

When a tab is clicked the class `selectionada` is added to your tab as well the class `visivel` is added to your content in order to show it.

So that sad if you want to use a button you will need then some additional `javascript` which has to add the class `selectionada` to the tab and the class `visivel` to the content you want to display.

Additionally the button has to know which the current open (`selectionada`) tab is in order to open the next one. Also if you use a `Next` button it seems to me logical that you will also need a `Previous` button.

I don't know your programming skills but this process involves some logic in order to be done.
If you are confident with `javascript` and `jquery` you can do this with some little effort.

Anyway you know now why just using a button as you ar doing, will not work.